# Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 1000 in descending order using Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Write a program that prints all numbers from 1 to 1000 in a large to small (descending) order.

Expected Output:

Each line will have a total of five (5) numbers and each number will be separated with a '\t' (Tab) character.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void main() {
  final output = StringBuffer();
  final columns = 5;
  final maxInt = 1000;
  var index =1;
  
  final values = List.generate(maxInt, (index) => index+1).reversed;

  while(index <= maxInt) {
    output.write('${values.elementAt(index - 1)}\t');
    if (index % columns == 0) {
      output.writeln();
    }
    index++;
  }
  
  print(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Her you go.

```
void main() {
  for (int i = 1000; i >= 1; i-=5) {
    print('${i}     ${i-1}     ${i-2}     ${i-3}     ${i-4}');
  }
}
```

Comment: This function produces the result in ascending order, while the question requests for descending order, the range is also incorrect  the question is for numbers from 1000 to 1 not 101.